# Parse: Anonymous like on a post

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I'm building an anonymous twitter like app with Parse where anyone can post to a newsfeed and upvote/downvote a post. The problem I'm having is saving the post for which an anonymous user upvoted or downvoted - so that when they do, it changes the color of the button. I learned that you have to make relations but am not sure how to save it and then query it.

The data for each post is stored in a class called "Sweets" and all the posts are saved in a local array called "timelineData".

Right now, I can easily increase the vote count for the post **but can't figure out how to find which post that user liked.**

Saving:

```
func upvote(sender: AnyObject) {

    let buttonPosition = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition) as NSIndexPath!

    let sweet:PFObject = self.timelineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as PFObject
    sweet.incrementKey("totalVotes", byAmount: 1)
    sweet["upVoted"] = true

    var user:PFUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    var relation = user.relationForKey("totalVotes")
    relation.addObject(sweet)
    user.saveInBackground()     

    self.tableView.reloadData()


}
```

Query'ing:

```
func loadData(){

        timelineData = []

        var findTimelineData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Sweets")

        findTimelineData.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (objects:[AnyObject]!, error:NSError!)->Void in

            if error == nil{

                for object in objects {
                    let sweet:PFObject = object as PFObject

                    self.timelineData.addObject(sweet)


                }
       }

}
```